# Should the DLQ on a Queue Manager *must* be a local queue on the QM?

Tags: ibm-mq

We are attempting to consolidate the DLQs across the board in our enterprise, into a single Q (an Enterprise_DLQ if you will...). We have a mix of QMs on various platforms - Mainframe, various Unix flavours - Linux,AIX,Solaris etc., Windows, AS/400....
The idea was to configure the DLQ on the QM (set the DEADQ attribute on the QM) to that of the ENTERPRISE_DLQ which is a Cluster Q. All the QMs in the Enterprise are members of the Cluster. This approach, however does not seem to work when we tested it. 
I have tested this by setting up a simple Cluster with 4 QMs. On one of the QM, defined a QRemote to a non-existent QM and non-existent Q, but a valid xmitq and configure the requsite SDR chl between the QMs as follows:

QM_FR - Full_Repos
QM1, QM2, QM3 - members of the Cluster

QM_FR hosts ENTERPRISE_DLQ which is advertised to the Cluster

On QM3 setup the following:
QM3.QM1 - sdr to QM1, ql(QM1) with usage xmitq, qr(qr.not_exist) rqmname(not_exist) rname(not_exist) xmitq(qm1), setup QM1 to trigger-start QM3.QM1 when a msg arrives on QM1

On QM1:
QM3.QM1 - rcvr chl, ql(local_dlq), ql(qa.enterise_dlq), qr(qr.enterprise.dlq)

Test 1:
Set deadq on QM1 to ENTERPRISE_DLQ, write a msg to QR.NOT_EXIST on QM3
Result: Msg stays put on QM1, QM3.QM1 is RETRYING, QM1 error logs complain about not being able to MQOPEN the Q - ENTERPRISE_DLQ!!

ql(qm1) curdepth(1)

Test 2:
Set deadq on QM1 to qr.enterprise.dlq, write a msg to QR.NOT_EXIST on QM3
Result: Msg stays put on QM1, QM3.QM1 is RETRYING, QM1 error logs complain about not being able to MQOPEN the Q - qr.enterprise.dlq (all caps)!!

ql(qm1) curdepth(2)

Test 3:
Set deadq on QM1 to qa.enterise_dlq, write a msg to QR.NOT_EXIST on QM3
Result: Msg stays put on QM1, QM3.QM1 is RETRYING, QM1 error logs complain about not being able to MQOPEN the Q - qa.enterise_dlq (all caps)!!

ql(qm1) curdepth(3)

Test 4:
Set deadq on QM1 to local_dlq, write a msg to QR.NOT_EXIST on QM3
Result: Msg stays put on QM1, QM3.QM1 is RUNNING, all msgs on QM3 ql(QM1) make it to local_dlq on QM3.

ql(qm1) curdepth(0)

Now the question: Looks like the DLQ on a QM *must* be a local queue. Is this a correct conclusion? If not, how can I make all the DLQs msg go to a single Q - Enterprise_DLQ above?

One obvious solution is to define a trigger on local_dlq on QM3 (and do the same on others QMs) which will read the msg and write it to the Cluster Q - ENTERPRISE_DLQ. But this involves additional moving parts - trigger, trigger monitor on each QM. It is most desirable to be able to configure a Cluster Q/QRemote/QAlias to be a DLQ on the QM. Thoughts/ideas???

Thanks
-Ravi

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa11240_.htm):

> A dead-letter queue has no special requirements except that:
>
> - It must be a local queue
> - Its MAXMSGL (maximum message length) attribute must enable the queue to accommodate the largest messages that the queue manager has
>     to handle plus the size of the dead-letter header (MQDLH)

The DLQ provides a means for a QMgr to handle messages that a channel was unable to deliver. If the DLQ were not local then the error handling for channels would itself be dependent on channels.  This would present something of an architectural design flaw.

The prescribed way to do what you require is to trigger a job to forward the messages to the remote queue.  This way whenever a message hits the DLQ, the triggered job fires up and forwards the messages.  If you didn't want to write such a program, you could easily use a bit of shell or Perl code and the Q program from [SupportPac MA01](http://SupptPacMA01).  It would be advisable that the channels used to send such messages off the QMgr would be set to not use the DLQ.  Ideally, these would exist in a dedicated cluster so that DLQ traffic did not mix with application traffic.

Also, be aware that one of the functions of the DLQ is to move messages out of the XMitQ if a conversion error prevents them from being sent.  Forwarding them to a central location would have the effect of putting them back onto the cluster XMitQ.  Similarly, if the destination filled up, these messages would also sit on the sending qMgr's cluster XMitQ.  If they built up there in sufficient numbers, a full cluster XMitQ would prevent all cluster channels from working. In that event you'd need some kind of tooling to let you selectively delete or move messages out of the cluster XMitQ which would be a bit challenging.

With all that in mind, the requirement would seem to present more challenges than it solves. Recommendation: *error handling for channels is best handled without further use of channels - i.e. locally.*

Comment: Thanks Rob - for your prompt response.